# Problems with grouping, mutating and showing expected values in R

Tags: r

I have a problem with grouping. I'm trying to group values from column A, and in the same time get every value of column C and multiply by 2, and for every grouped value from column A calculate mean and, at the same time, select only those values from column A that mean is higher than 75. After that, I want to show boxplot using grouping every value from column C by Column B.

I will just give an example. I have dataframe like this:

```
df=data.frame((cbind(c('01-May', '01-May', '01-May', '02-May', '02-May', '02-May','03-May','03-May','03-May','04-May','04-May','04-May')
      ,c('15:00', '16:00','17:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','15:00' ,'16:00','17:00')
      ,c(25,54,34,28,38,48,36,25,34,04,59,22))))
```

The data looks like this:

```
A      B     C
01-May 15:00 25
01-May 16:00 54
01-May 17:00 34
02-May 15:00 28
02-May 16:00 38
02-May 17:00 48
03-May 15:00 36
03-May 16:00 25
03-May 17:00 34
04-May 15:00 04
04-May 16:00 59
04-May 17:00 22
```

Now I want to multiply C column by 2.

```
A      B     C
01-May 15:00 50
01-May 16:00 108
01-May 17:00 68
02-May 15:00 56
02-May 16:00 76
02-May 17:00 96
03-May 15:00 72
03-May 16:00 50
03-May 17:00 68
04-May 15:00 08
04-May 16:00 118
04-May 17:00 44
```

Next I would like to see calculated mean for every day (column A), and select only these which mean is higher than 75, so:

```
A     C
01-May 75.3
02-May 76
```

Finally I would like to show only those days in `boxplot(df$B~df$C)` to see how boxes look like for every hour (column B).

How can I group like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach

- groups by `day` to calculate the daily mean,
- compares the daily mean against the threshold of 75 and saves result to `keep_day`, and
- `filter`s rows belonging to days above that threshold.

Even if scores are below the threshold, they are displayed in the boxplot, as long as they were taken on a day whose mean was above the threshold.

```
library(magrittr)
ds <- structure(list(day = c("01-May", "01-May", "01-May", "02-May", 
  "02-May", "02-May", "03-May", "03-May", "03-May", "04-May", "04-May", 
  "04-May"), time = c("15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "15:00", "16:00", 
  "17:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00"
  ), score = c(25, 54, 34, 28, 38, 48, 36, 25, 34, 4, 59, 22)), row.names = c(NA, 
  -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ds <- 
  ds %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    score  = score * 2
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(day) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    score_mean_daily    = mean(score),
    keep_day            = (75 < score_mean_daily)
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::filter(keep_day)

boxplot(ds$score ~ ds$day)
```

*Results*:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  day    time  score score_mean_daily keep_day
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>            <dbl> <lgl>   
1 01-May 15:00    50             75.3 TRUE    
2 01-May 16:00   108             75.3 TRUE    
3 01-May 17:00    68             75.3 TRUE    
4 02-May 15:00    56             76   TRUE    
5 02-May 16:00    76             76   TRUE    
6 02-May 17:00    96             76   TRUE
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
days <- c('01-May', '01-May', '01-May', '02-May', '02-May', '02-May','03-May','03-May','03-May','04-May','04-May','04-May')
hours <- c('15:00', '16:00','17:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','15:00' ,'16:00','17:00')
scores <- c(25,54,34,28,38,48,36,25,34,04,59,22)

df <- data.frame(days, hours, scores)
df

df <- data.frame(days, hours, scores = scores*2)
df

df <- filter(df, df$scores > 75)
df

boxplot(df$hours, df$scores)
```